# How to download Ubuntu One onto iPad?

Tags: apple, ipad

How can I download Ubuntu One onto my Apple iPad so I can sync with my other devices?

Answer (score 1):

Sadly; there is no iPad App. but you may use the compatible iPhone App that will also work on your iPad.

1- From You iPad, open App store and search for Ubuntu One Files and/or Ubuntu One Music (Remember to search iPhone Apps)

2 You may also get them from https://one.ubuntu.com/downloads/iphone/ and you will have a direct links to the App Store